# won't show progressDialog in android

Tags: android

I have a to load a progressdialog in a second activity that I have in my android project after push a button but the pogressdialog doesnt load it.
Could you help me please?
Thanks and sorry for my english!

The code is...

```
ent enviar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v){
        calcularFecha(horaIn,horaFi);
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Log.d("PRUEBA", "COMENZAMOS LA PARTE DE LA CONEXION");
        //getApplicationContext()
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(programacion.this, "", "Loading...");

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    sleep(10000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("PRUEBA", e.getMessage());
                }
                // dismiss the progress dialog
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should manage (show / remove) the progress dialog from within the UI thread instead of your custom thread.

This solution works for me, if I have the `progressDialog` member defined inside my current activity:

```
enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Log.d("PRUEBA", "COMENZAMOS LA PARTE DE LA CONEXION");
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(programacion.this, "", "Loading...");
        calcularFecha(horaIn, horaFi);
        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(10000);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("PRUEBA", e.getMessage());
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

The progress dialog is shown for 10 seconds, then it gets dismissed.

What you have to make sure, is:

1. your are inside the `programacion`
   activity (that is specified in your
   `ProgressDialog.show` method).
2. The `calcularFecha(horaIn, horaFi);`
   doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: Nothing works!
I've saw that if I put a simple toast also don't show it! :-(
enviar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
    
    public void onClick(View v){
    
     
    calcularFecha(horaIn,horaFi);
       
       Log.d("PRUEBA", "COMENZAMOS LA PARTE DE LA CONEXION");
             Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"WOL + CONEXTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Toast.makeText( programacion.this,"WOL + CONEXTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       //getApplicationContext()
       Log.d("PRUEBA", "MOSTRAMOS PROGRESS");
...........

Comment: i've shared a sample code that works just fine. please take a look, and if you still have problems, please share your stack trace from LogCat. thanks!

Comment: Thanks.Now it works. I dont know what happens. I comment the next lines of the code that I have. These lines are:         if (pruebaPing("221.221.221.2")){
         Log.d("PRUEBA","No llega despues de comprobar el primer ping. Hay que mandar paquete");
         
            new tareaWOL().execute();
            
        }else{
         dialogin.dismiss();
         new tareaPing().execute();  
       }. I cant understand why with these lines not working???????

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(activity.this);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
progressDialog.show();

if(progressDialog!=null)
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    System.out.println("dialog dismissed");
}
```

try this

Comment: Nothing works! I've saw that if I put a simple toast also don't show it! :-( enviar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v){ calcularFecha(horaIn,horaFi); Log.d("PRUEBA", "COMENZAMOS LA PARTE DE LA CONEXION"); Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"WOL + CONEXTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); Toast.makeText( programacion.this,"WOL + CONEXTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //getApplicationContext() Log.d("PRUEBA", "MOSTRAMOS PROGRESS");

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you..

ProgressDialog update = new ProgressDialog(activity.this);

update.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                        update.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                        update.setCancelable(true);
                        update.setMax(100);
                        update.show();

```
                    Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
                           public void run() {
                               try {
                                   // enter the code to be run while displaying the progressbar.
                                   //
                                   // This example is just going to increment the progress bar:
                                   // So keep running until the progress value reaches maximum value
                                   while (update.getProgress()<= update.getMax()) {
                                       // wait 500ms between each update
                                       Thread.sleep(500);

                                       // active the update handler
                                       progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                                   }

                               } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
                                   // if something fails do something smart
                               }
                           }
                        });

                        // start the background thread
                        background.start();
                        if(update.getProgress()== 100)
                           {
                               update.dismiss();
                           }
```

Comment: Nothing works! I've saw that if I put a simple toast also don't show it! :-( enviar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v){ calcularFecha(horaIn,horaFi); Log.d("PRUEBA", "COMENZAMOS LA PARTE DE LA CONEXION"); Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"WOL + CONEXTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); Toast.makeText( programacion.this,"WOL + CONEXTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //getApplicationContext() Log.d("PRUEBA", "MOSTRAMOS PROGRESS");

Comment: Try to put the on clicklistener in this way...                             Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(Classname.this,"Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
    
   });

Answer (score 0):

I think your `ProgressDialog` is attached to the wrong `Activity` (eg `Context`).

You did not post the full class source code, but the problem could be `programacion.this`:

```
ProgressDialog.show(programacion.this, "", "Loading...");
```